# Show or Hide Rows when section is tapped in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have made a custom view for section in tableview using `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` but and when button is tapped on a section iam reloading tableview. It reloads table for that section but remaining sections are not shown.

I don't know how to do this. code for `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` is

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (!selected) {

    headerView = [[[HeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:HeaderFrame] autorelease];

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    headerView.label.text = @"title";

    headerView.button.tag = section;

    headerView.tag = section;

    [headerView.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     return headerView;
}
else if (selectedIndex == section && selected){

    [headerView.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Croped-Rotated.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return headerView;
}
else 
    return headerView;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain in detail,exactly what you want to do?

Comment: John Abruzzi: hey fish where is febonchi lol .. this may help you sir http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139 - this might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {



    headerView = [[[HeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:HeaderFrame] autorelease];

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    headerView.label.text = @"title";

    headerView.button.tag = section;

    headerView.tag = section;

    [headerView.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (selectedIndex == section && selected){

    [headerView.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Croped-Rotated.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return headerView;
}
else 
    return headerView;
}
```

Try this. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (!selected) {

    headerView = [[[HeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:HeaderFrame] autorelease];

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    headerView.label.text = @"title";

    headerView.button.tag = section;

    headerView.tag = section;

    [headerView.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     return headerView;
}
else if (selectedIndex == section && selected){

    [headerView.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Croped-Rotated.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return headerView;
}
else 
    return headerView;
}
```

As per your code `if (!selected)` then `headerView` get allocated other wise not.
So perform allocate work before the `if` condition As @jyotishree mention.